# textTheme not set to text style flutter

Tags: flutter

Im trying to set `textTheme` on Text using `style` parameter of `Text()` like below:

```
Text('Hello Flutter',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)
```

but it is not working and this is the result:
[image: 1]

but when i don't set `style` it will work:
[image: 2]

The problem is, i want to set `bodyMedium` on my `Text(style: )` but it did not work.
This is the whole code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle defaultTextStyle = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'IranYekan');
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyMedium: defaultTextStyle.copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900, fontSize: 50),
          bodySmall: defaultTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 40),
        ),
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home:  Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child:  Text('Hello Flutter',style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

What is the problem? how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to the `context` not having the updated `ThemeData` when it’s being used.

In Flutter, the `context` in the widget tree doesn’t immediately have access to the changes above it. When you use `build(context)`, it provides the `context` that contains the updated `ThemeData`.

To ensure that the `Text` widget uses the updated theme, you can wrap it in a `Builder` widget, which provides a new `BuildContext` that has access to the updated theme. Here’s how you can modify your code:

```
home: Builder(builder: (context) {
 return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
   child: Text('Hello Flutter',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)),
   );
}),
```

or create a custom widget like:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello Flutter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium)),
    );
  }
}
```

For more information, look at: [`BuildContext`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html) class.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I have one another question, is it related to widget lifeCycle? What should i read about to know more?

Comment: Take a look at: [`BuildContext`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext-class.html)  class.